# Passing an object to settings using drupal_add_js

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm working on a module that will generate a graph using Google's chart api.  The data used to generate the chart uses date objects because I'm graphing race times, like this

```
[
    ['Number', 'Time'],
    ['1', new Date(2014, 5, 5, 0, 1, 47, 470)],
    ['2', new Date(2014, 5, 5, 0, 1, 45, 880)],
    ['3', new Date(2014, 5, 5, 0, 1, 43, 520)],
    ['4', new Date(2014, 5, 5, 0, 1, 40, 670)]
]
```

I want to generate this using PHP and am having trouble passing this to the script.  The code I have to generate the data looks like this

```
$jsData = array();
$jsData[] = array("Number","Time");

foreach($records_nodes as $node) {
  $number++;
  $uTime = strtotime("2014-01-01 0:$time");

  $hundreths = isset($node->field_racetime[$node->language]) ? substr($node->field_racetime[$node->language][0]['time'],-2) : 0;

  $jstime = sprintf("new Date(%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d)",
      2014,
      1,
      1,
      12,
      date("m",$uTime),
      date("s",$uTime),
      $hundreths  * 10
  );
  $jsData[] = array("$number",$jstime);
}
drupal_add_js(array('records_view' => array('data' => $jsData)), 'setting');
```

This works well. I can see the data being passed to `Drupal.settings.records_view.data`. However, the second element (the `new Date` part) is being passed as a string:

```
['1', 'new Date(2014, 5, 5, 0, 1, 47, 470)'],
```

Is there a way to pass this as the JavaScript object?